# Remove Target name from list of targets in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a script using a txt file with about 80 targets for the script. I am using a ForEach loop to cycle thru the targets. What I am trying to do is figure out a way to modify the source file removing the names of computers that were successful and leave the ones that failed. This is the script so far:

```
$computers = Get-Content -Path C:\Temp\Computers.txt
$Credentials = Get-Credential
$Credentials.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Set-Content C:\temp\password.txt
$Username = $Credentials.Username
$Password = Get-Content “C:\temp\password.txt” | ConvertTo-SecureString
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $Username,$Password
$file1 = "C:\Temp\installer.msi"
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'


ForEach($computer in $computers){

# See if Computer is online before proceeding

IF (Test-Connection -BufferSize 32 -Count 1 -ComputerName $computer) {

$b = New-PSSession -computername $computer -Credential $Credentials

# Create c:\Temp if it doesn't already exist

Invoke-Command -Session $b -ScriptBlock {
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path C:\Temp -Force
}

#Copy Installer to Local Temp Directory

Copy-Item -path $file1 -Destination "C:\Temp\" -ToSession $b

# Install msi

Invoke-Command -Session $b -ScriptBlock {
$Arguments = "/i", "`"C:\Temp\installer.msi`"", "/qn", "/norestart", "ALLUSERS=1", "/L*v", "`"c:\temp\msisetup.log`""
$msiProcess = Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList $Arguments -PassThru

# Check if installation was successful 
# 0 = ERROR_SUCCESS, 3010 = ERROR_SUCCESS_REBOOT_REQUIRED
if( $msiProcess.ExitCode -in 0, 3010 ) {
   Write-Host "Installation succeeded with exit code $($msiProcess.ExitCode)"
}


}

# Wait for Install to finish completely

$Seconds = 60
$EndTime = [datetime]::UtcNow.AddSeconds($Seconds)

while (($TimeRemaining = ($EndTime - [datetime]::UtcNow)) -gt 0) {
  Write-Progress -Activity 'Watiting for Sleep to Finish' -SecondsRemaining $TimeRemaining.TotalSeconds
  Start-Sleep 1
}

# Cleanup

Invoke-Command -Session $b -ScriptBlock {
Remove-Item -Path C:\Temp\installer.msi

}

$List = "C:\Temp\computers.txt"
$string = "$computer"
$ListContent = Get-Content $List
$measureureObject = $string | Measure-Object -Character
$index = $ListContent.IndexOf("$computer")
$length = $measureureObject.Characters
$ListContent.Remove($index,$length) | Set-Content $List


} Else {
Continue
}
}
```

The section near the end when it gets to the $ListContent.Remove line it gives me the following error:

Cannot find an overload for "Remove" and the argument count: "2".
At line:7 char:1

- $ListContent.Remove($index,$length) | Set-Content $List
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
  ```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way. I just added this to the Else end of the If/Else

```
} Else {
"$computer" | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Temp\OfflineComputers.txt" -Append
Continue
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the way I'd do it, way easier than trying to edit the exiting file as you go through it. :)